# How to control div on hover:?

Tags: css, html, menu, background-color

I found a way to change the background color of a menu option upon hover.  However, when you hover an option, it takes up some wide space that moves all the other options to the right, its sort of annoying, i want to maintain a consistent space, so if i hover, only the color should change, not the option moving to the right.  Sort of the way facebook has its menu options.

Below is the code:

```
  <div id="menu">
  <a href="/hello" id="option">home</a>
  <a href="/hello" id="option">profile</a>
  <a href="/hello" id="option">account</a>
  <a href="/hello" id="option">settings</a>
  <a href="/hello" id="option">extra</a>
  <a href="/hello" id="option">logout</a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  div#menu {
  margin-left: 630px;
  margin-top:-20px;
  }
  option {
  margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #option:hover{
  background: #3F2327;
  padding: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Possible solution: Using &nbsp; before and after a menu option gives me the look i need.  But not sure if thats a good practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `padding: 10px;`

Space around an element takes up space, so if you don't want space, don't add it. If you want it all the time, add it all the time and not just for `:hover`

---

Also, unrelated to your problem, but just good practises:

- If you use a browser that doesn't support CSS, has it turned off, or isn't graphical you end up with *home profile account settings extra logout* — you have a list of links, use [list markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html). There is plenty of [guidance on making it pretty](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/).
- An id must be **unique** in a document, only use it to identify a specific element. Use the class attribute if you want to state that a bunch of elements are all members of the same class.
- Avoid using class and id names that are the same as [HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION), it just makes code confusing

Comment: There is whitespace between those anchors, so it would actually render a very readable "home profile account settings extra logout". Not to say it's not a really good idea to use a proper HTML list anyways, just that this isn't the reason.

Comment: I don't need the space, correct.  But i am using padding so the empty space to the left and to the right of the option also changes color.  This is adding the white space.

Comment: @coreyward — good point, athough it is still a problem for browsers (such as lynx) which don't underline links - you can't tell where one ends and the next begins.

Comment: @AAA — You are adding *extra* space though, not colouring existing space. As I said, use list markup and look at listamatic, it has lots of examples of this sort of thing. Style things properly. If you add padding, then add it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

1) You are missing a # on "option"

2) Why are you padding on hover? That will cause a movement when you hover above it.

Comment: i am using padding so the empty space to the left and to the right of the option also changes color.  This is adding the white space.